# `git diff` not working for files excluded from Git LFS

Tags: git, git-lfs

Our repo (https://github.com/code-dot-org/code-dot-org) has recently converted to using Git LFS. We have large static web directories in Git, which admittedly isn't a great pattern. Our approach has been to include these large directories in LFS, and then exclude certain "known to be text" file types within them.

Here is an example of this approach in `.gitattributes`:

```
pegasus/sites.v3/** filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text # include dir in LFS
pegasus/sites.v3/**/*.haml !text -filter -merge -diff # exclude *.haml from LFS
```

However, `git diff` isn't behaving as expected with the exclusions, say I modify `pegasus/sites.v3/hourofcode.com/views/front_join_us.haml`. This is included by dir pattern, but then excluded by a more specific file extension pattern, however when trying to get a `git diff`, it claims the file is binary and won't diff them:

```
diff --git a/pegasus/sites.v3/hourofcode.com/views/front_join_us.haml b/pegasus/sites.v3/hourofcode.com/views/front_join_us.haml
index aaf209c98be..2de745be618 100644
Binary files a/pegasus/sites.v3/hourofcode.com/views/front_join_us.haml and b/pegasus/sites.v3/hourofcode.com/views/front_join_us.haml differ
```

Additionally, it won't auto-merge the files. What's mysterious is that some tools, like VSCode, can properly diff this file.

I've confirmed that `front_join_us.haml` is NOT tracked by LFS:

```
git lfs ls-files | grep front_join_us.haml # returns nothing
```

UPDATE: @LeGEC suggested using `git check-attr -a -- <path>` to check the attributes on the file. Results were:

```
> git check-attr -a -- pegasus/sites.v3/hourofcode.com/views/front_join_us.haml
pegasus/sites.v3/hourofcode.com/views/front_join_us.haml: diff: unset
pegasus/sites.v3/hourofcode.com/views/front_join_us.haml: merge: unset
pegasus/sites.v3/hourofcode.com/views/front_join_us.haml: filter: unset
```

It appears the "exclude from LFS" gitattributes patterns generated by `git lfs import` do not actually return the file to default attributes... how do I get filter, diff and merge back to their default values (so git check-attr reports not attributes) vs unset as they are now?

Comment: the generic binary detection is just based on detecting a zero byte in the beginning of the file (first 4 kb ? not sure about the window size). You can force text diff by running `git diff --text`. If that works, you may hunt for the faulty byte in either version of the file.

Comment: The files have no zero bytes, but I believe gitattributes is tricking them into thinking they are binary before they are even sniffed.

Comment: you may debug how attributes are applied to a file using [`git check-attr -a -- <path>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-attr)

Comment: Oh that's super helpful thank you @LeGEC, I've updated my question with the results of running check-attr since I can't put block pastes in comments.

Comment: Aha! It seems that git attributes differentiates between "unset" and "unspecified" (https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes). The default .gitattributes output by `git lfs import` were unsetting the diff/merge/filter attributes they set, but NOT unspecifying them (which would return them to their defaults). Some git ecosystem tools (e.g. github's merge/diff) interpret unset as similar to unspecify, and some don't (e.g. git diff).

Comment: I've changed the exclude-from-lfs pattern in .gitattributes to be like this instead: `pegasus/sites.v3/**/*.haml !text !filter !merge !diff`, and now I'm getting diffing! @LeGEC do you want to answer the question? Otherwise I'll self answer to be of service to somebody down the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pointed out in your comment that you suspected an issue with the attributes that applied to your files, to debug attribute issues, you can use [`git check-attr`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-attr):

```
git check-attr --all -- path/to/file
```

---

It turns out that setting the attributes this way:

```
# .gitattributes:
pegasus/sites.v3/**/*.haml !text -filter -merge -diff # exclude *.haml from LFS
```

leads to having all these attributes to "unset":

```
$ git check-attr -a -- pegasus/sites.v3/hourofcode.com/views/front_join_us.haml
pegasus/sites.v3/hourofcode.com/views/front_join_us.haml: diff: unset
pegasus/sites.v3/hourofcode.com/views/front_join_us.haml: merge: unset
pegasus/sites.v3/hourofcode.com/views/front_join_us.haml: filter: unset
```

which is *not* the same as having them "unspecified":
quoting [`git help gitattributes`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes)

> Each attribute can be in one of these states for a given path:
> [...]
> **Unset**
> The path has the attribute with special value "false"; this is specified by listing the name of the attribute prefixed with a dash - in the attribute list.
> [...]
> **Unspecified**
> No pattern matches the path, and nothing says if the path has or does not have the attribute, the attribute for the path is said to be Unspecified.

having the `diff` flag "unset" is what leads to the missing diff issue.

---

By changing the gitattributes rule to :

```
# .gitattributes: use '!' instead of '-'
pegasus/sites.v3/**/*.haml !text !filter !merge !diff # exclude *.haml from LFS
```

the attributes return to "unspecified" and the diff returns.